# Ionic 2 with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 (beta11) and Google maps.  I have a page that works fine, and it displays the map as expected.

To access this page, I click on an item and the page is loaded via `this.nav.push(MapPage, {`. As you can see the map loads:

[image]

However, when I go up another level, and do `this.nav.push(MapPage, {` again (displaying the same page), the page is displayed, but the map looks like this:

[image]

So it has navigated from one page to the same page, but the second time the map is not visible.

Here is my code:

**html**

```
  <ion-card id="map" class="job-map"></ion-card>
```

**map.ts**

```
  load(bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds): void {
    let mapOptions = {
      center: bounds.getCenter(),
      zoom: 15,
      maxZoom: 15,
      minZoom: 1,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var htmlElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("map");
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(htmlElement, mapOptions);
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
    this.ref.markForCheck();
    this.mapLoading = false;
  }
```

If anyone can offer any suggestions, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is it because there are two pages on the stack, and both pages have the same element with id "map", and it is only applying it to the first one?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was because there were two pages on the stack with the same element id of "map". If I give each page a unique id, it works.

Comment: I'm having same problem, so how did you assign the `page a unique id`?  #ionic2 If possible post an update (answer) in your answer.